# How to capture dynamic content from element inside an iFrame?

Tags: iframe, playwright

When I try to capture text from an element inside an iFrame where the element content changes every second, I get "undefined". What might I be doing wrong?

Code:

````
const { firefox } = require('playwright');
const fs = require('fs');
var url = 'http://jsfiddle.net/6vnam1jr/1/show';
var section_path = 'xpath=/html/body/div/div/div/section';
var iframe_path = 'xpath=/html/body/div/iframe';
var text_path = 'xpath=//html/body/div[2]/div[2]';
async function getElementText(browser,page){
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.click(section_path);
  
  const frame = await page.$(iframe_path);
  const contentFrame = await frame.contentFrame();
  await sleep(1000);
  let handle = await contentFrame.$eval(text_path);
  console.log(handle)
  
  // try again
  await sleep(1000);
  handle = await contentFrame.$eval(text_path);
  console.log(handle)
  
  closeBrowser(browser);
}
async function closeBrowser(browser){
  await browser.close();
}
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
(async () => {
  const browser = await firefox.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  getElementText(browser,page);
})();```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the repro. [frame.$eval](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.4.2&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pageevalselector-pagefunction-arg) is an API to run a JS function in the browser which takes the element as an argument.

I believe what you are looking for is an [ElementHandle](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.4.2&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=class-elementhandle) to this element. You can use [frame.waitForSelector](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.4.2&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=framewaitforselectorselector-options) or [frame.$](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.4.2&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=frameselector) for this purpose. I have verified that they are not undefined.

```js
// ...
let handle = await contentFrame.waitForSelector(text_path);
```